# Having issue with aligning a image in center of fixed nav bar when page size changes

Tags: html, css, web

I'm having some trouble with this wedding website I'm making for school. The problem being that the center decoration piece witch will eventually be a logo, doesn't align with the top of the page when the screen size is changed. On the screen I'm working on it looks fine, but on other screens it gets messed up.

Screen I'm working on. Looks fine.

[image: demonstration]

Friend's Screen is moved down or on other screens is cut off.

[image: demonstration]

I have tried everything from changing the position type and the display type, trying to set margins. To even setting it fixed and then positioning it where I want it, but always ends up messing something else up. The nav bar is fixed at the top of the screen and the surrounding links are aligned to it. I can't seem to solve it and am wondering if anyone has any solutions.

Here is a link to the download for the website:[Website](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7KV4qpJFc2CUDE5X2U2YjRIcFE/view?pref=2&pli=1)

```css
@import url('http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=entypo');
html{
    background-image: url("background.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:0px 60px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    padding:0px;
}
body{
    margin:0;
}
nav{
    background-color: snow;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    z-index: 100;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

section{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
    background-color: dimgrey;
    z-index:50;
    margin-left:15%;
    margin-right:15%;
}
footer{
    font-size: 13px;
    z-index: 75;
    font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    color: slategray;
    margin-top:60px;
    top:60px;
    background-color: #ddd;;
    height:60px;
    margin-left:15%;
    margin-right:15%;
    padding: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -4px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px -4px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px -4px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

nav ul{
    text-align: center;
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

nav ul li{
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    margin:0px;
}
nav ul li a{
    margin-left:-2px;
    margin-right:-2px;
    color: slategray;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:25px;
    font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, 'Segoe UI', Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 7px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    height: 10%;
    width:9%;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
    background-color:#d9d9d9;
}
nav ul li a:active{
   background-color:#d9d9d9;
}
nav ul li img{
    z-index: -20;
    align-content: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 75px;
    background-color: snow;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-top:-210px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-bottom:7px;
    padding-top:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius:50%;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
.wedding{
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
h1{
    background-color: snow;
    font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, 'Segoe UI', Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
.footer-info{
    margin: 0;
    list-style:none;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
}

.ui-datepicker,
.ui-datepicker table,
.ui-datepicker tr,
.ui-datepicker td,
.ui-datepicker th {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/* Calendar Wrapper */
.ui-datepicker {
    display: none;
    width: 294px;
    padding: 35px;
    cursor: default;
    margin-left:20px;

    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;

    background: snow;

    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1), inset 0px 1px 1px rgb(0,0,0);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1), inset 0px 1px 1px rgb(0,0,0);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1), inset 0px 1px 1px rgb(0,0,0);
}

/* Calendar Header */
.ui-datepicker-header {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}

.ui-datepicker-title { text-align: center; }

/* Month */
.ui-datepicker-month {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: #565656;
}

.ui-datepicker-month:before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 0;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    content: '';

    background: #a5cd4e;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a5cd4e 0%, #6b8f1a 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#a5cd4e), color-stop(100%,#6b8f1a));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%);

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Year */
.ui-datepicker-year {
    padding-left: 8px;
    color: #a8a8a8;
}

/* Prev Next Month */
.ui-datepicker-prev,
.ui-datepicker-next {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-datepicker-prev {
    left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.ui-datepicker-next {
    right: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.ui-datepicker-prev span,
.ui-datepicker-next span{
    display: block;
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    text-indent: -9999px;

    background-image: url(../img/arrows.png);
}

.ui-datepicker-prev span { background-position: 0px 0px; }

.ui-datepicker-next span { background-position: -5px 0px; }

.ui-datepicker-prev-hover span { background-position: 0px -10px; }

.ui-datepicker-next-hover span { background-position: -5px -10px; }

/* Calendar "Days" */
.ui-datepicker-calendar th {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;

    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #a8a8a8;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar td {
    padding: 0 7px;

    text-align: center;
    line-height: 26px;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default {
    display: block;
    width: 26px;
    outline: none;

    text-decoration: none;
    color: #a8a8a8;

    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

/* Day Active State*/
.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-active {
    color: #6a9113;
    border-color: #6a9113;
}

/* Other Months Days*/
.ui-datepicker-other-month .ui-state-default { color: #565656; }

.social {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: Entypo;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #555;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.wrapper {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}

.social {
  box-shadow: rgb(210, 210, 210) 1px 1px,
    rgb(210, 210, 210) 2px 2px,
    rgb(211, 211, 211) 3px 3px,
    rgb(211, 211, 211) 4px 4px,
    rgb(211, 211, 211) 5px 5px,
    rgb(212, 212, 212) 6px 6px,
    rgb(212, 212, 212) 7px 7px,
    rgb(212, 212, 212) 8px 8px,
    rgb(213, 213, 213) 9px 9px,
    rgb(213, 213, 213) 10px 10px,
    rgb(214, 214, 214) 11px 11px,
    rgb(214, 214, 214) 12px 12px,
    rgb(214, 214, 214) 13px 13px,
    rgb(215, 215, 215) 14px 14px,
    rgb(215, 215, 215) 15px 15px,
    rgb(215, 215, 215) 16px 16px,
    rgb(216, 216, 216) 17px 17px,
    rgb(216, 216, 216) 18px 18px,
    rgb(216, 216, 216) 19px 19px,
    rgb(217, 217, 217) 20px 20px,
    rgb(217, 217, 217) 21px 21px,
    rgb(218, 218, 218) 22px 22px,
    rgb(218, 218, 218) 23px 23px,
    rgb(218, 218, 218) 24px 24px,
    rgb(219, 219, 219) 25px 25px,
    rgb(219, 219, 219) 26px 26px,
    rgb(219, 219, 219) 27px 27px,
    rgb(220, 220, 220) 28px 28px,
    rgb(220, 220, 220) 29px 29px,
    rgb(221, 221, 221) 30px 30px;
   text-shadow: rgb(226, 226, 226) 1px 1px,
    rgb(227, 227, 227) 2px 2px,
    rgb(227, 227, 227) 3px 3px,
    rgb(228, 228, 228) 4px 4px,
    rgb(229, 229, 229) 5px 5px,
    rgb(229, 229, 229) 6px 6px,
    rgb(230, 230, 230) 7px 7px,
    rgb(230, 230, 230) 8px 8px,
    rgb(231, 231, 231) 9px 9px,
    rgb(232, 232, 232) 10px 10px,
    rgb(232, 232, 232) 11px 11px,
    rgb(233, 233, 233) 12px 12px,
    rgb(233, 233, 233) 13px 13px,
    rgb(234, 234, 234) 14px 14px,
    rgb(235, 235, 235) 15px 15px,
    rgb(235, 235, 235) 16px 16px,
    rgb(236, 236, 236) 17px 17px,
    rgb(236, 236, 236) 18px 18px,
    rgb(237, 237, 237) 19px 19px,
    rgb(238, 238, 238) 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><img src="img/hearts.png"></li>
            <li><a href="">Reservations</a></li>
            <li><a href=""="">Menue</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <img src="img/wedding.jpg" class="wedding">
    </section>
    <footer>
        <ul class="footer-info">
            <li> <p>Made by Taylor Bastian and Danial Andales for FBLA competition</p> </li>
            <li><p>Copyright © 2015. SampleCorp</p></li>
        </ul>

         <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="social">&#62220;</div>
            <div class="social">&#62217;</div>
            <div class="social">&#62223;</div>
            <div class="social">&#62232;</div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You don't maybe want to put this on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Try using "em" instead of pixels. pixel's are the same size on every screen and so they do not adjust to your screen, however, "em"s will be the same relative size on all screens, meaning that it will adjust to your screen. Hope this helped, I'm a newbie too. :P

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with spaces, margin, padding sizes, in a large browser everything will works fine but in a small browser like  width 1024px, the elements will move because they don't have enough space.

Change some css in
`nav ul li img` change `top:-13px`
It fix your example, if not, use media query, to large browser maybe is `top:0` for smaller browser use the accurate `top:xx`,
have fun.